# Leaking `.gnupg` directory when private keys are stored on a smart card

Tags: gnupg

What security risks can be caused by leaking `.gnupg` directory (for example, accidentally committing it to GitHub) when private keys are stored on a smart card?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good reason this folder normally has permissions set to `700` and it certainly should not be published.

- `gpg.conf` contains your GnuPG configuration. If there's some weak settings, it might be usable information for targeted attacks. Most has some default configuration from the distribution, which makes this the least interesting file.
- `pubring.gpg` contains all your contacts (and your own public keys). It's like leaking your address book, but worse: it possibly has information specifically on all the contacts you would rather communicate in private with.
- `trustdb.gpg` contains your entire trust database. That may reveal weak points if you trust some keys too much, and helps further in mapping your (most private) social network.